# How to trigger a flow during undeployment of a Mule application in CloudHub?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, cloudhub

I am working on a use case to trigger a specific flow that should trigger only when undeployment of the application happens from CloudHub.

I found an article that has script and  am using the same to find out the flow start:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/scripting-module/2.0/scripting-module-examples

Can you help me to find out the way to trigger a flow after undeployment is initiated from CloudHub?

Comment: What are you doing at application startup with your script exactly? It is not clear if that method could be used at application undeployment without more information.

Comment: @aled At the application start am calling another service to make database entries. Now want to delete the entries at the time of undeployment.

Comment: Please share un example in the question.

Comment: Are you using any CICD for deployments?

Comment: @AnuragSharma No . This logic is part of process api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that. The script execution happens inside a flow execution, that is probably triggered by a scheduler at startup. There is no way to trigger a flow at shutdown of the Mule application. Note that it should be at shutdown, because undeployment is a CloudHub event that the Mule Runtime is not aware of. At undeployment CloudHub commands Mule to shutdown the application.